# How to separate each row in an ArrayList of 1000 numbers with only 20 numbers printed?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

currently trying to figure out to how to complete an issue. I wish to print 1000 random numbers but only having 20 number per row printed. Aka, only have 20 numbers in each line printed instead of 1 line of 1000 numbers.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo {
    static int pick;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // create an array list
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int j = 0; j<1000; j++){
        pick = rand.nextInt(100);
        al.add(pick);
       if (j == 20){
        System.out.println(" "); 

       } 
    }

    System.out.println(al);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the System.out.println(" "); with this and remove the conditional with j == 20.
Iterate through a loop and at every 20th spot insert a next line.

```
for(int x =0; x< al.size();x++)
{
  System.out.print(al.get(x)+" "); 
 // prints on the new line until the conditonal below is true again
   if(x%20==0)
   {
       System.out.println(""); // moves to next line 
   }


}
```

Comment: This seemed to work for most of the numbers but it seemed to have printed a lot more numbers then 1000. Help?

Comment: Your loop is correct. It may "look more than 1000" but it should be 1000 numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.add(r.nextInt(100));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (i % 20 == 0 && i != 0) {
                System.out.println(list.get(i) + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```